# Необходимо заблокировать кнопку на 1 час! при этом, чтобы время блокировки продолжалось после закрытия страницы!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо заблокировать кнопку на 1 час! При этом, чтобы время блокировки продолжалось после закрытия страницы!

Answer (score 3):

Постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые вопросы. 
А так же прикладывать собственные попытки реализации.
Учитывая, что это первый Ваш вопрос - добавил ответ. 
Но выполнение задач за других не приветствуются, по-этому в следующий раз выкладывайте, пожалуйста, то , что пробовали реализовать самостоятельно.
Это не сайт выполнения задач на заказ, а сайт помощи.

Можно использовать куки или `localstorage`

Вот пример с `cookie` (Для проверки скопировать себе. в сниппете куки не передаются):

```js
    function getCookie(name) { // Функция получения куки по имени
        let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
            "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
        ));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }

    var checkbutt = document.getElementById('but');
    checkbutt.disabled = true;
    function checkButton() {
        var time = new Date();  // Получаем текущую дату
        var cookie = getCookie('clicked'); //Получаем куки по имени через функцию
        var dif = 0; // Если нет значения в куки, то останется 0
        if (cookie){ //Если куки существую, то
            let cookieTime = new Date(cookie); // Преобразуем значение куки в дату
            let dif1 = time - cookieTime; // Вычитаем текущее время минус время куки, чтобы получить разницу.
            dif = Math.round(dif1/1000); // округляем и делим на 1000(это миллисекунды)
        }
        var z = document.getElementById('text'); // получаем значение куда записывать (для теста
        var duration = 60; // Длительность между нажатиями.Поставил 60 секунд для демонстрации. Заменить 1200, если нужен час.

        if (dif > duration || dif == 0) { // Если длительность больше указанного времени, или равно 0, то выполняем операцию
            checkbutt.disabled = false;
        } else {
            checkbutt.disabled = true;
            var f = duration - dif; // получаем разницу для вывода сенкуд. Можно будет поменять до минут и так далее, смотря как надо выводить
            z.innerText = "До повторного нажатия кнопки подождите "+f+" секунд"; // Выводим сообщение с таймером секунд.
        }
    }

    setInterval(checkButton, 500);


    but.onclick = function () { // При нажатии кнопки
        var time = new Date();
        document.cookie = "clicked=" + time; // Записываем данные в куки по имени.

    }
```

```html
<div id="text">Нажми на кнопку</div>
<button id="but">Тык</button>
```

Comment: Прошу меня простить за мою дерзость. Первый раз как никак. У меня функция срабатывает при загрузке на страницу, но не при нажатии на кнопку. Что делать?

Comment: @Nameless Проверьте, пожалуйста, что данные перенесены в Ваш скрипт корректно, и что нет уже записи в `cookie`. Проверил ещё раз у себя - всё работает корректно. Суть в том, что при запуске проверяется куки, если запись в ней есть, то кнопка будет не активной, если записей нет, то кнопка становится активной.

Comment: А если пользователь очистит свои родные куки? :-)